# Silverlight RC0 Upgrade Issue

Tags: silverlight

Since upgrading to RC0 from SL2 B2 the following line of code in my Page.xaml gives a `AG_E_PARSER_BAD_PROPERTY_VALUE`...anyone have any ideas?  I didn't see anything in the breaking changes document.  It seems to be the binding mode in the snippet below.

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Source={StaticResource ProductListDS}}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to do this in a header template?  If so, this appears to be a bug in RC0
http://silverlight.net/forums/p/30592/98478.aspx

Also it appears to be an issue with the new ComboBox control in RC0.

Bart Czernicki
[www.silverlighthack.com](http://www.silverlighthack.com)